# Testing a solidity smart contract with Truffle: how to make it to pass all test cases?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I'm trying this smart contract which has functions to set and get a user. I'm also testing it on JavaScript with mocha and chai tools and for all of this I use Truffle. But the thing is that for the test case "should Add New User", I'm not getting this test case to pass and I realized that when I'm calling `this.storageContract.getUser` function and storaging its result on user constant, if I print its content I'm not getting the data I stored when calling `this.storageContract.setUser`, so when I use checkUserData function, it does not pass.

I wonder how can I make this test case to pass, because I can't find the error for which it currently fails the test. I deployed this smart contract on Remix IDE and it works well, so the problem must be on the test script.

This is Solidity Smart Contract:

```
contract SupplyChainStorage is SupplyChainStorageOwnable {
    address public lastAccess;

    constructor() {
        authorizedCaller[msg.sender] = 1;
        emit AuthorizedCaller(msg.sender);
    }

    event AuthorizedCaller(address caller);
    event DeAuthorizedCaller(address caller);

    event UserUpdate(address userAddress);
    event UserRoleUpdate(address userAddress);

    modifier onlyAuthCaller() {
        lastAccess = msg.sender;
        require(authorizedCaller[msg.sender] == 1);
        _;
    }

    struct User {
        string name;
        string contactNo;
        bool isActive;
        string profileHash;
    }

    mapping(address => User) userDetails;
    mapping(address => string) userRole;

    mapping(address => uint8) authorizedCaller;

    function authorizeCaller(address _caller) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        authorizedCaller[_caller] = 1;
        emit AuthorizedCaller(_caller);
        return true;
    }

    function deAuthorizeCaller(address _caller)
        public
        onlyOwner
        returns (bool)
    {
        authorizedCaller[_caller] = 0;
        emit DeAuthorizedCaller(_caller);
        return true;
    }

    User userData;
   
    function setUser(
        address _userAddress,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _contactNo,
        string memory _role,
        bool _isActive,
        string memory _profileHash
    ) public onlyAuthCaller returns (bool) {
        userData.name = _name;
        userData.contactNo = _contactNo;
        userData.isActive = _isActive;
        userData.profileHash = _profileHash;

        userDetails[_userAddress] = userData;
        userRole[_userAddress] = _role;

        emit UserUpdate(_userAddress);
        emit UserRoleUpdate(_userAddress);
        return true;
    }

    function getUserRole(address _userAddress)
        public
        onlyAuthCaller
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return userRole[_userAddress];
    }

    function getUser(address _userAddress)
        public
        onlyAuthCaller
        returns (
            string memory name,
            string memory contactNo,
            string memory role,
            bool isActive,
            string memory profileHash
        )
    {
        User memory tmpData = userDetails[_userAddress];
        return (
            tmpData.name,
            tmpData.contactNo,
            userRole[_userAddress],
            tmpData.isActive,
            tmpData.profileHash
        );
    }
}
```

This is JavaScript test:

```
const SupplyChainStorage = artifacts.require('SupplyChainStorage');

const _name = 'Mat';
const _contactNo = '0979081091';
const _role = 'PROCESSOR';
const _isActive = true;
const _profileHash = 'Qmadp4L61MaQPX5NFfjqaihnY8r7PmogqZL6wvX1HqvL';

contract('SupplyChainStorage', function(accounts){
    const spenderAddress = accounts[0];
    const authorizedCaller = accounts[1];
    const userAddress = accounts[2];

    beforeEach(async() => {
        this.storageContract = await SupplyChainStorage.new({from:spenderAddress, gas: 6000000});
    });

    it('should Authorize', async() => {
        const {logs} = await this.storageContract.authorizeCaller(authorizedCaller,{from: spenderAddress});

        const authorizedCallerEvent = logs.find(e => e.event === 'AuthorizedCaller');
        assert.exists(authorizedCallerEvent, "AuthorizedCaller does not exists");
    });

    it('should DeAuthorize', async() => {
        const {logs} = await this.storageContract.deAuthorizeCaller(authorizedCaller, {from: spenderAddress});

        const deAuthorizeCallerEvent = logs.find(e => e.event === 'DeAuthorizedCaller');
        assert.exists(deAuthorizeCallerEvent, "DeAuthorizedCaller does not exists");
    });

    it('should Add New User', async() => {

        const {logs} = await this.storageContract.setUser(userAddress,_name, _contactNo, _role, _isActive, _profileHash)

        const updateUserEvent = logs.find(e => e.event === 'UserUpdate');
        assert.exists(updateUserEvent, "UserUpdate does not exists");
    
        const updateUserRoleEvent = logs.find(e => e.event === 'UserRoleUpdate');
        assert.exists(updateUserRoleEvent, "UserRoleUpdate does not exists");

        const user = await this.storageContract.getUser(userAddress, {from: spenderAddress});
        console.log(user);

        assert.equal(user[0],_name,"Name checked:");
        assert.equal(user[1],_contactNo,"Contact No checked:");
        assert.equal(user[2],_role,"Role checked:");
        assert.equal(user[3],_isActive,"isActive checked:");
        assert.equal(user[4],_profileHash,"Profile Hash checked:");
    });
})
```

This is the log I get when running `truffle test --network ganache` command:

```
  2 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: SupplyChainStorage
       should Add New User:
     AssertionError: Name checked:: expected undefined to equal 'Mat'
      at checkUserData (test/SupplyChainStorage.js:66:12)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/SupplyChainStorage.js:49:9)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Comment: What does `console.log(user)` return?

Comment: @Pobepto, this returns ```{
  tx: '0xfc960d9cb640d87c76f37ac58b44b86e1e796a94be77d2e69e7ee0cebc3a0fda',
  receipt: {
    transactionHash: '0xfc960d9cb640d87c76f37ac58b44b86e1e796a94be77d2e69e7ee0cebc3a0fda',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0x71f70dc9eeb32ab892201ce9c14d7479ef4c0f005aec325d0fb8f12cae16cc3f', blockNumber: 618,
    from: '0xd93a549569c963372bdace998a6b707626254ecd',
    to: '0x9f3657f892260b92c773e3a34a71d05aaa6d0373',
    gasUsed: 36154,cumulativeGasUsed: 36154,
    contractAddress: null,logs: [], status: true, logsBloom: '0x, rawLogs: [], }, logs: []}  },
```

Comment: @Pobepto, But I realized if I delete `onlyAuthCaller
` modifier on getUser and getUserRole functions on the smart contract and I use view, this works.

Comment: My guess is that because you don't have a `view` function, you are getting a transaction object. Maybe you should fix the contract and make the `view` function. I guess this will help - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/53073/95940

Comment: @Pobepto, and when printing user constant I get: ```Result {
  '0': 'Mat',
  '1': '0979081091',
  '2': 'PROCESSOR',
  '3': true,
  '4': 'Qmadp4L61MaQQX5NFfjqaihnY8r7PmogqZL6wvX1HqwL',
```

Comment: @Pobepto, thanks for the link. It helps me to realize that because when consulting `this.storageContract.getUser`, I was not writing data, I need this instead: `this.storageContract.getUser.call(userAddress)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
const user = await this.storageContract.getUser(userAddress, {from: spenderAddress});
```

to this:

```
const user = await this.storageContract.getUser.call(userAddress, {from: spenderAddress});
```